# "The method setConfig(Properties) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

Tags: java, ant

I have imported the project "ant" in eclipse, but I have the problem above in the package org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh, in the class SSHBase, for the followings lines of code:

```
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

    bla bla bla...

    final Session session = jsch.getSession(userInfo.getName(), host, port);
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
            "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
    session.setUserInfo(userInfo);
```

Comment: From what class is the object `session` ? Are you sure to have imported the correct `Session` class?

Comment: I think com.jcraft.jsch.Session, but not sure. I have edited the question

Comment: [This is bizarre, the method exists](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.java#Session.setConfig%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

Comment: Maybe I didn't import the correct version of the library? I have imported the 0.1.53

Comment: I sincerely don't know since I've never used this library.