# setConfig(Properties) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)”

Tags: java, session, jsch

This question has already been asked here: ["The method setConfig(Properties) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34239833/7812989)
more than a year ago but it doesn't have any answer and I have the same problem just now.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything more on Google.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties 

JSch jsch = new JSch();
String user = "myUserId";
String host = "myHost";
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
```

My code is as simple as that and I have the following message:

> The method setConfig(Properties) in the type Session is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, String).

So I tried another way to do the same thing, but it's not normal that it doesn't work. Does anyone know where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three overloads of the `Session.setConfig` in latest JSch 0.1.55:

```
public void setConfig(java.util.Properties newconf)
public void setConfig(java.util.Hashtable newconf)
public void setConfig(String key, String value)
```

If you do not have the third overload, you must be using some very old version of JSch. The overload was introduced in JSch 0.1.34 in 2007!

Comment: Ok, nice ! Thank you, I have 0.1.31 so that's it ! I thought I had downloaded the last one... Have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setConfig-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

as said in documentation it's a static method so it should be the 'Session' where Session is the class not and object session. i hope you understand the difference.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I get the difference, but I don't understand why the code works in this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108923/file-transfer-using-java-jsch-sftp
I don't see any difference between this code and mine... I would like to do the same

Comment: @zenki1201 That's `JSch.setConfig`, while the question is about `Session.setConfig`.